# php laravel binding mockery instance failed

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, testing, mocking

I try to mock a class with Mockery.
I create a new Laravel projet.

I create the controller **app/Http/Controllers/Mockcontroller.php** with contents :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Mockcontroller extends Controller
{
    function get($id) {
        return 'FAILED';
    }
}
```

I want to mock the **get()** method, so I have modified the file **tests/ExampleTest.php** with this contents :

```
    <?php

    use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

    class ExampleTest extends TestCase
    {
        /**
         * A basic functional test example.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function testBasicExample()
        {
            $mock = Mockery::mock(App\Http\Controllers\Mockcontroller::class);
            $mock->shouldReceive('get')
                ->with(10)
                ->andReturn('SUCCESS');
            $this->app->instance(App\Http\Controllers\Mockcontroller::class, $mock);

            $ctrl = new App\Http\Controllers\Mockcontroller();
            dd($ctrl->get(10));


        }
    }
```

But when I run the following command :

```
vendor/bin/phpunit
```

I get this output

```
PHPUnit 5.7.5 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

"FAILED"
zsh: exit 1     vendor/bin/phpunit
```

When I replace this line **dd($ctrl->get(10));** by the following line :

```
dd($mock->get(10));
```

I get the right text : SUCCESS.

So, that's mock injection that failed.

Do you have a way to correctly inject my mock ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `$ctrl = new App\Http\Controllers\Mockcontroller();` you create a new instance of controller without using app container, and consequently the mock.

Since you set your mock as `$this->app->instance(App\Http\Controllers\Mockcontroller::class, $mock);` you need to get is as `$this->app->make(App\Http\Controllers\Mockcontroller::class);`, but to be completely honest, I don't see much sense in what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Originally, I create the mock on a Eloquent repository but I wanted to create one from blank Laravel project. So I use a  Controller. With your answer I get an error, $this->app doesn't contains get() method : PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::get() in /var/www/to.auzuret/tetsmock/tests/ExampleTest.php on line 27
I use Laravel 5.3

Comment: Sorry, of course it is `$app->make`, not `$app->get`

Comment: Thank you it works ! So, I short-circuited the Laravel contain system by using this path system App\Controller\... Thanks again